# ¿En qué momento y parte se inicializan los atributos de una clase en JAVA a su valor por defecto?

Tags: java

Tengo entendido lo siguiente:

1. Sé que si tenemos una clase y no creamos un constructor, el compilador de java crea un constructor vacío por defecto inicializando los atributos a su valor por defecto.
2. Además si creamos un constructor no vacío el compilador ya no crea el constructor vacío.

Entonces me surgió la siguiente duda. Si tenemos una clase Persona con un constructor creado

```
public class Persona {

    String nombre;
    int edad;
    int ntelefono;
    
    public Persona(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    
}
```

Creo una clase Main con el método main para instanciar la clase Persona y mostrar por pantalla los atributos del objeto creado:

```
    public class Main {
    
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Persona p = new Persona("frank");
        System.out.println(p.nombre);
        System.out.println(p.apellido);
        System.out.println(p.edad);
        System.out.println(p.ntelefono);
    }
}
```

Me muestra por consola lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda está ¿En qué parte de la ejecución del programa y donde es que se inicializan los atributos apellido, edad y ntelefono a su valor por defecto?. Si yo no los inicialicé en el constructor de la clase Persona, además como dije al crear un constructor no vacío el compilador ya no añade un constructor vacío.

Answer (score 5):

Los atributos de instancia (aquellos no `static`) son inicializados con el valor por defecto correspondiente a su tipo de dato (`0` para los tipos numéricos primitivos, `false` para el tipo `boolean` y `null` para los *reference types*) después de crearse el objeto y antes de llamar a cualquiera de sus constructores.

Los atributos estáticos son inicializados luego de que la clase es cargada en memoria por el `ClassLoader`.